# How to bind @variables in inserted functions in coffiescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Code:

```
    class FileTree
      constructor: (@root_elem, @options, @handler) ->

      _bind_tree: (t) ->
        that = this
        $(t).find('li a').bind('click', ->
          func1 = (elem) =>
            if( @options.some_option ) 
      ...
```

The problem that `@options` converts to `_this.options` that is wrong for this content: `_this` is a `var _this = this` in case of `=>` function.

I solve this issue with using `that` variable like in pure Javascript:

```
 ...

func1 = (elem) =>
    if( that.options.some_option ) 
 ...
```

Are there any pretty solution without using interim variables?

Comment: you can bind the callback to lock in the this to be your tree instead of the dom node. i don't know about in coffee, but in js, you can simple append " .bind(this)" inside the event-binding parens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want `@options` to be the `@options` from the FileTree constructor, you need to use the fat-arrow on the click handler too:

```
class FileTree
  constructor: (@root_elem, @options, @handler) ->

  _bind_tree: (t) ->
    $(t).find('li a').bind('click', =>
      func1 = (elem) =>
        if @options.some_option
          doStuff()
```

Which compiles to:

```
FileTree.prototype._bind_tree = function(t) {
  var _this = this; // will refer to the instance of FileTree
  return $(t).find('li a').bind('click', function() {
    var func1;
    return func1 = function(elem) {
      if (_this.options.some_option) {
        return doStuff();
      }
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mark one more detail: I need reference for element in binded function. That why I used `->` arrow here: `$(t).find('li a').bind('click', ->`